# StatusBar overlaps NavigationPage on Android from Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image]

As shown in the image, when updating Xamarin forms from the latest 2.3.3 version to the first 2.3.4 version, the statusbar overlaps the navigation bar. This behaviour ist still there in current version 2.4.0.38779. No code was changed between those both images despite the Xamarin.Forms update.

I use a MasterDetailPage, where the detail part contains a navigation page with a ContentPage inside. No custom stuff, just the default pages.
I cannot find any issues relating this nor any breaking changes documented explaining this change in behaviour.

For me it seems the correct display is the variant in version <2.3.4. Or is the new display correct and I have to set some flag to pull the navigation bar beneath the statusbar?

PS: I use Prism.Forms as framework.

Comment: any updates on this? how did you pull navigation bar beneath status bar

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can also have a look here for the corresponding PR: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1116 and here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59185 and also nice to know: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101986/transluscent-statusbar-android-in-2-3-4pre1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Problem is solved in Xamarin 3

ORIGINAL:

To answer my own question:

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment:

There is a pull request regarding the issue: [PR](http://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1116)

And a renewed Pull request: 
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1287

The bug report: [Bugzilla](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59185)

Thread from BjornB who suggested the PR: [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101986/transluscent-statusbar-android-in-2-3-4pre1)