# Android Layout: Display view under StatusBar

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

What is the best way to display my layout under the StatusBar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_900">

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Navigate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:MvxBind="Click GoToMainScreenCommand"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

In the screenshot of the tower you can see that the StatusBar overlaps my button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StatusBar overlaps NavigationPage on Android from Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080032/statusbar-overlaps-navigationpage-on-android-from-xamarin-forms-2-3-4)

Comment: @SagarZala No, this is a Xamarin.Forms problem that has already been solved